# Autodesk Forge Markup Extension Error Create Switch button Error

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I have referred Markup extension from [This Website](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html)

**The extension is loading fine only when I click on extension button I get an error on the line**

[image]

**Which gives me an error**

[image]

I have rechecked the code from the main code and there is no definition for creating switch button. So, How can I resolve that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post is a bit old now, some parts are obsolete. The `createSwitchButton` was imported from another file using `require`...

Your best option would be to take a look at the updated version of the Markup UI sample that I created. You can find it there: [Viewing.Extension.Markup2D](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Markup2D)

The live version is [here](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598d7ec14cabf2c1f4dec948) and is combined with another extension [Viewing.Extension.ConfigManager](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.ConfigManager) to let you save the markups in database for persistency. It works with the latest version of the viewer, `2.17` at the time of this writing.

[image]

Comment: Thank You @Philippe Leefsma